# Open appstore via itms-apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

i'm trying to open an app in appstore from an UIAlertView When the otherButtonTitle. The problem is nothing is happening.

I've checked when the otherButton is pressed if this method is called and it is. The problem lies in the openURL i guess. the appId contain an name of an app without any whiteSpace like "youtube". How come the link is not opening? i've tried looking in other threads and this is the code that should open an app in appstore

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:   (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString *appId = [[otherArray objectAtIndex:currentRow] objectForKey:@"link"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/%@?mt=8", appId]]];

    }


}
```

Comment: check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break it down into smaller steps and debug the steps.

First, is the didDismiss method  being called.

Next, is the code inside the if statement being executed.

The easiest way to figure this out is to set a breakpoint on the code that assigns appID and then make sure your code breaks there.

After that line executes, make sure appId contains the string you expect it to.

Net, you should rewrite the last line into steps that first create the URL, THEN call openURL. Step through the code that creates the URL to make sure it is being created correctly.

You might want to copy the URL string and paste it into a browser to see if it works from there.